# Meaning of “like” in sentence below

Tags: meaning

> It says something on the wall like you said to me before.

In this sentence Does “like” mean that it says something in the way you said or it says something like thing you said before? If it has not two meanings , What should I say for these situtaion ?

Comment: The example sentence is not grammatical!  If you wrote it correctly, it could be ambiguous or could mean only one of those, depending on the exact words.

Comment: The main problem is "like you said me" - it sounds like the object of "said" is "me", which does not make sense - people are not things that are said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this sentence Does “like” mean that it says something in the way you said or it says something like thing you said before?

It could have either meaning.

"It says something on the wall" probably means something *written* on the wall, so "A like B" is probably answering *what?* and not *how?*.  That probability is around 60%.

If the second object of *says* was a person and not a thing, it'd more likely be *how?*.  But only slightly more likely.

Only context could tell for sure.

To rewrite to tell the difference, you can do this:

> It says something on the wall, something you said to me before.
>
> It says something on the wall, you said it that way to me before.